# Solving a differential equation $F-y'F_{y'}=C$, with $F(y,y')= \frac{1+2y'^2}{3y^3\sqrt{1+y'^2}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

If $$F= F(y,y')= \frac{1+2y'^2}{3y^3\sqrt{1+y'^2}},$$

where $y=y(x)$ and $y'= y'(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}$, then how to solve the differential equation:

$$F-y'F_{y'}=C, $$

that is:

$$F(y,y')-\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=C,$$

where $C$ is some constant? What are the keys steps? I got a very hairy differential equation when I tried solving this directly by doing the calculations. Is there some substitution trick etc. that I should apply here?

Comment: By direct calculation, we can get $3y^3(1+y'^2)^{3/2}=1/C$. This looks solvable to me.

Comment: Thank you, I will try get to that =)

Comment: Thank you @KittyL I noticed I did a stupid mistake. In my haste I wrote $F_{y'}$, but I integrated w.r.t $x$ and that's why I got it so hairy x)

Comment: what does $y'F_{y'}$ and $F$ mean? what are the parameters?

Comment: Hi @ADG I edited my post. $F= F(y,y')$. Did this make things clear? $F$ is a function of $y$ and $y'$.

Comment: and does $F_{(y')}=F(y',y'')$??

Comment: No, $F_{y'}=\displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=F_{y'}(y,y')$

Comment: OK, but please edit your quetsion

Comment: Is it more clearer now? :)

Comment: @jjepsuomi Did you manage to solve the problem using the answer given by KittyL? Or do you still need help?

Comment: @Mattos not yet, I'm still trying :) If you want to show some of the steps I'm not against this. But I will try to do it myself also ;)

Comment: @jjepsuomi Sure, I'll provide an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$\begin{align} \\
F(y,y') &= \frac{1 + 2y'^{2}}{3y^{3} \sqrt {1+y'^{2}}} \\
&= \frac{1}{3y^{3}}\bigg[(1 + 2y'^{2})(1 + y'^{2})^{\frac{-1}{2}}\bigg]
\end{align} $$

As there is no explicit $x$ dependence, we can find a first integral of the form

$$\begin{align} \\
y'\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} - F &= y'\cdot\frac{1}{3y^{3}}\bigg[4y'(1+y'^{2})^{\frac{-1}{2}} + (1 + 2y'^{2})\cdot\frac{-1}{2}\cdot2y'(1+y'^{2})^{\frac{-3}{2}}\bigg] - \frac{1}{3y^{3}}\bigg[(1 + 2y'^{2})(1 + y'^{2})^{\frac{-1}{2}}\bigg] \\
&= \frac{1}{3y^{3}}\bigg[(3y'^{2} + 2y'^{4})(1 + y'^{2})^{\frac{-3}{2}}\bigg] - \frac{1}{3y^{3}}\bigg[(1 + 2y'^{2})(1 + y'^{2})^{\frac{-1}{2}}\bigg] \\
&= \frac{1}{3y^{3}}\bigg[\frac{3y'^{2} + 2y'^{4} -(1 + 3y'^{2} + 2y'^{4})}{(1+y'^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}\bigg] \\
&= \frac{1}{3y^{3}}\bigg[\frac{-1}{(1+y'^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}\bigg] \\
&= C
\end{align} $$

(I omitted a few steps of algebra, if you would like me to put them in just write a comment below).

Hence we get

$$\begin{align} \\
(1+y'^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}} &= \frac{-1}{3y^{3}C} \\
\implies (1+y'^{2})^{3} &= \bigg(\frac{1}{9y^{6}C^{2}}\bigg) \\
\end{align} $$

Where in the last step we squared both sides.

Therefore,

$$\begin{align} \\
1 + y'^{2} &= \bigg(\frac{1}{9y^{6}C^{2}}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{3}} \\
\implies y'^{2} &= \bigg(\frac{1}{9y^{6}C^{2}}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{3}} - 1 \\
&= \alpha^{2}\cdot\frac{1}{y^{2}} - 1 \\
\implies y' &= \pm \bigg(\alpha^{2}\cdot\frac{1}{y^{2}} - 1\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
&= \pm \bigg(\frac{\alpha^{2} - y^2}{y^{2}}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
&= \pm \frac{\sqrt{\alpha^{2} - y^2}}{y} \\
\end{align} $$

With

$$\alpha^{2} = \bigg(\frac{1}{9C^{2}}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

Separating and integrating we get

$$ \int \frac{y}{\sqrt{\alpha^{2} - y^2}}  dy = \pm \int dx $$

where the **LHS** can be solved using a trig substitution.

For the future, a *general* method for solving maximising/minimising problems goes like this (this solution recipe is a grave oversimplification, but it may help you get used to these types of problems):

**1)** If there is no independent variable dependence ($x$ or $t$ or whatever other variable it might be), find a first integral using the formula

$$ y'\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} - F = C $$

**2)** Substitute your functions $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}$ and $F$ into your equation.

**3)** Solve for $y'$

**4)** Separate and integrate

If you have any questions or you see a mistake in my algebra, just let me know in the comments.